# How to find where a user has not submitted by month and year

Tags: sql, date

Thanks for the time in reading and/or responding to my question. All help appreciated.

I have been asked to write a SQL query to find out which users have not completed a survey for a particular month. Basically every user has to complete a survey once a month (anytime during that month) which gets recorded in a table.

```
Table.Users

ID  UserID  Name
1   10      Jon Doe
2   20      Jane Doe

Table.Survey

ID  UserID  DateSubmitted
1   10      01/01/2016
2   10      02/02/2016
3   10      03/03/2016
4   10      04/04/2016
5   10      05/05/2016
6   10      06/06/2016
```

Output (This would show the month and year the user has not submitted a survey.

```
UserID  Month   Year    DateSubmitted
10      1       2016    01/01/2016
10      2       2016    02/02/2016
10      3       2016    03/03/2016
10      4       2016    04/04/2016
10      5       2016    05/05/2016
10      6       2016    06/06/2016
10      7       2016    NULL
10      8       2016    NULL
10      9       2016    NULL
10      10      2016    NULL
10      11      2016    NULL
10      12      2016    NULL
```

Comment: mysql **or** sql-server ?

Comment: Create a table of months and do a left join to your Surveys.

Comment: @AP08 Why have a field called UserId on Users table? Table.Users.Id should be PK, and Table.Surveys.UserId FK

Comment: Thanks for your help @SqlZIm i used your query but created a calendar table instead and the query runs perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server: using an adhoc `months` table, `cross join` to `users`, and `left join` to `Survey`

```
declare @StartDate     date = '20160101'
       ,@NumberOfYears int  = 1;

;with Months as (
select top (12*@NumberOfYears) 
      MonthStart = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate)
    , MonthEnd   = dateadd(day,-1
        , dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number), @StartDate))
    , Month = month(dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate))
    , Year  = year(dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate))
  from master.dbo.spt_values
)

select u.UserId, m.Month, m.Year, s.DateSubmitted
  from Users u
    cross join Months m
    left join Survey s
      on u.UserId = s.UserId
     and s.DateSubmitted >= m.MonthStart
     and s.DateSubmitted <= m.MonthEnd
where u.UserId = 10
```